# Unable to GET value from redis

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, redis

I am trying to get a value from redis which I have set. When I call the checkCache function I get "CACHE: null" and afterwards it logs "NO ERROR + the data". I dont understand why since I used await.

```
const redis = require("redis");
const client = redis.createClient({
  port      : procces.env.PORT,
  host      : procces.env.HOST,
  password  : procces.env.PASSWORD,
});

const checkCache = async (key) => {
  await client.get(key, (err, data) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("NO ERROR + " + data);
    if(data !== null) { return JSON.parse(data); }
  });
  return null;
};
```

I call the methode like this:

```
const findAll = async(user) => {
  const cache = await checkCache(user);
  console.log('CACHE: ' + cache);  // returns null
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Module `redis` doesn't support Promise.

For this you have promisify it

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const redis = Promise.promisifyAll(require("redis"));
```

EDIT:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const redis = Promise.promisifyAll(require("redis"));
const client = redis.createClient({
  port      : process.env.PORT,
  host      : process.env.HOST,
  password  : process.env.PASSWORD,
});

const checkCache = async (key) => {
  const data = await client.getAsync(key);
    console.log("NO ERROR + " + data);
    if(data !== null) { return JSON.parse(data); }
  return null;
};
```

Comment: I tried this but it still returns null and afterwards the "NO ERROR + the data"

Comment: @r10lomo this is returning the value of the key. I have tried the above code.

Comment: It worked is there like a any other package which does not need bluebird? I tried redisio and it did not work

EDIT: 
Im sorry I did not see the getAsync at first.

Comment: @r10lomo if you don't want to use bluebird you can use 
`promisifyAll = require('util-promisifyall')` to promisify all